# How do I select element which are dynamically generating from drop down menu using selenium?

Tags: java, html, selenium, junit, webdriver

Sometimes in drop down list, you need to select content which is generating dynamically. Let's take an example, In drop down search box, if I enter 'Social' then drop down option like 'Social Media' is generated. I want to select that generated content. How do I do that?

HTML code look like:

```
<div id="xyz"  class="togglebox" style="display:none">
<div class="formItem">
<label >What is your business?</label>
<div class="input"><select name="abc" class="validate" id="qwerty"><option value="" selected="selected">Please select...</option>
<option value="AC1">Accountant</option>
<option value="SM">Social Media</option>
<option value="AS">Antique Shop </option>
```

I want to select my business as Antique shop. How do I do that? Each time I select it by value it throws the error 'Element is not visible'

Comment: Can you provide some HTML for such a scenario?

Comment: Here is my html code look like:

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, could you now provide a sample of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use the method called 'selectByIndex' Here is how to do it.

```
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("id of the dropDown")));
dropDown.selectByIndex(int);
```

Here pass integer as the index. The first value in the drop down is at index 0, then next value is at index 1 so on. So if you want to select the 2 nd value what you have to do is this.

```
    Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("id of the dropDown")));
    dropDown.selectByIndex(1);
```

Comment: I hope you know how to locate element using a locator. I have taken By.id locator. You can use any.